# How to make Application for Both iOS and Android in AWS MobileHUb?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I have created AWS MobileHub for iOS platform. All DynamoDB tables and Userpools are connected to iOS Mobile Hub project.

Now client wants this application in Android also.

But when i Create AWS MobileHub for the Android app and create dynamoDB, it create seperate tables from ios table.

But i want that both application use same tables not diferent.

How can i make both app use same DynamoDB tables and Userpool in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

The latest documentation for building apps (IOS and Android) are here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-mobile.html

If you are interest in [ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) please checkout the [AWS Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/react_native_guide).